# cookie configuration on magento 1.9.2.0

Tags: magento, cookies, configuration

I'm working on Magento 1.9.2.0. and I have a cookie problem on its config.
I found many topics the right way to config cookie but when

config 1: i put the domain path without dot(.) (domaine.com) login on device does not work.

config 2: if i put the dot, login on PC does not work.(.domaine.com)

Now, we have a multistore website. when you loggin (with config 1), the name in customer account changes randomly, 
and config2 does not work(no one can log in).

Anyone can help me!

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71702/login-does-not-work-because-of-subdomain-cookie#comment145277_71702

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it was the cache. header template was not regenerated while reloading page. 
After reseting cookies configuration, it works but still has connexion pb on mobile device.